# Connecting Analog GND and Digital GND of ADC

Tags: adc, analog, design, ground, grounding

I'm trying to make a simple line tracing robot, however I couldn't figure out how to connect AGND and DGND of A/D converter(MCP3208) on a simple perfboard design. I need some guidance how to smooth out the noise for AGND and how to connect these two grounds.

[The A/D converter that I'm using(MCP3208)](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/808967.pdf)

Thank you!

Comment: What does the data sheet say that confuses you?

Comment: @Andyaka Actually the general connection of ADCs confuses me. Because I hardly managed to provide a stable Vref using zener diode, however, now most of the people says do not connect the AGND and DGND directly. I couldn't find any simplified design that could fit into my simple application. Do I really need to seperate these two GNDs?

Comment: So what advice does the DS give you that is confusing? Also note that the DS says AGND and DGND are connected internally on the chip via 5 to 10 ohms. Single ended measurements are always a risk because 0V at one end of your robot aint gonna look the same as the other end.

Comment: `Section 6.5 Utilizing the Digital and Analog Ground Pins`

Comment: @Andyaka Nothing in DS, it's actually the web that confused me Telling me to separate pins. So what connection doyou recommend for this particular chip, I can check that as an answer because It'll provide straightforward explanation to make me understand. I'm using all 8 CHs to IR sensor array, SPI communication with FPGA, I got 4.7V zener diode and 1k Resistor to provide Vref, the only thing left is the grounding, thats what I couldn't figure out, because I'm newbie in electronics, knowing the necessity of separation of these two grounds, I couldn't figure out how to connect those GND pins .

Comment: @Passerby I mean is it just that? http://www.edaboard.com/thread27478.html in this link people says it must be separated

Comment: There is no easy answer because, unless you are doing differential measurements the ground noise along your wiring will upset readings.

Comment: The manufacturer's suggested wiring is typically the best. And separating the AGnd from DGnd is only important if your DGnd is noisy. And that happens from switching. A line follower robot, your using batteries and most likely only turning the motors on and off, not using PWM. You don't have the noise or precision needs that will affect it, imho.

Comment: @Andyaka What about an Reflectance sensor array QTR-8A? Is it worth taking these precautions and making the grounding better for simple sensor array? Would it make so much difference in my readings if I were to connect two grounds? I just need to see whether plane is white or black, thats all.

Comment: @Passerby It actually is noisy, it not only traces a line, It solves a maze that was made up of these lines(black electric tape). For other peripherals (such as LCD etc.), It has I2C interface, SPI interface(With ADC), and indeed it has motor controller circuit with PWM, thats what worries me. Especially SPI will run at 1 or 2 MHz clock rate.Also, 400 kHz for I2C. The total perfboard is about 3 cm by 7cm. I did my best to divide the whole circuit into two as analog and digital however, the ADC part that worries me about possible noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your level of experience, I suggest you focus on making a single low impedance ground. Separate analog and digital grounds never benefit digital circuitry. If they are not done correctly, they also do not benefit analog circuitry. So just ground everything together (no separate analog and digital ground). Use boards with continuous solid ground planes. You can also make an artificial GND plane on a single layer board using copper tape.

If you have to run wires from board to board, make half of the wires GND. In other words, for every signal that goes from board to board, there should also be a ground wire. For every power connection that goes from board to board, there should also be a ground wire. Twist each power or signal wire with its dedicated GND. This will save you a lot of trouble.

Each board should have room for a large bulk capacitor of at least 220 uF. This is in addition to the 0.1 uF per power pin and/or whatever is recommended by the chip vendor.

Order a kit of cable ferrites so that you have it ready just in case you have unexpected noise problems. The board-to-board wires can be routed through the ferrites to suppress high frequency noise.

In the schematic, place small resistors in series and small capacitors to ground on the analog inputs coming back from the reflectance array. Basically you want to be able to make an RC low-pass filter at each input. On the layout, place these RC components close to the actual analog input. Make sure you have an array of different resistor and capacitor values on-hand so you can tune the cutoff frequency of the RC filter.

Good luck! Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start on how to connect gnds is the following link:

http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/Anniversary/12.html

Comment: Here, we summarise link contents in the post. It's so that if the link changes, the answer isn't invalidated